# How to make the CGImage resolution dependence?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage

I want to crop an Image, so, I google, and find this article:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-crop-an-image.html

But the problem is in this line:

`CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);`

I realize that the if the image is on non-retina display, it cut perfectly, but if there is on an retina device, the rect's frame's width and height need to multiple 2. But the question is, how can I make it more generic? (I don't want to detect device) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had overcome the same with the following code:

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect {
rect.size.height = rect.size.height * [image scale];
rect.size.width = rect.size.width * [image scale];
rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x * [image scale];
rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y * [image scale];
CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [image CGImage];
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImageRef, rect);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef scale:[image scale] orientation:[image imageOrientation]];
CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
return newImage;
}
```

Hope this helps.